# Is it safe to dispatch the same action to multiple Redux stores?

Tags: node.js, redux, redux-saga

I have a NodeJS application using Redux on the server for state management. I have multiple sibling Redux stores, and these stores are also running sagas.

> (I'm not looking to discuss the merits of the multiple store approach,
> I have a Redux store per player, it was a considered decision and it
> works well for me)

I have a number of places where I am doing this, creating a new action for each:

```
for (const player of players) {
    player.store.dispatch(playerChatAction(senderId, message));
}
```

I am wondering if there are likely to be any issues with creating a single action and dispatching it to them all.

```
const action = playerChatAction(senderId, message);

for (const player of players) {
    player.store.dispatch(action);
}
```

Comment: What kind of issues?

Comment: I don't see conceptually why it would be dangerous.  Actions are (or should be treated as) immutable, and your reducer is likely matching on a type property or something?

Can't imagine this is a common use case though so probably best just to test it.  Might be worth paying attention to the redux dev tools while you do to see if you notice anything funky (know you said server side - dunno if there are tools there or if you could run a test in the browser instead).

Comment: @DaveNewton no idea, possibly not triggering subsequent sagas correctly. I just know that this is a weird thing to do and curious as to any problems it might bring

Comment: @JamesMonger Does each store have it's own saga middleware? So `const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()` for each store?

Comment: Yes it does @HMR